# preg match variable to not treat as a string

Tags: php, preg-match

```
   $custom_sizes = array(); 
   foreach (array('small', 'medium', 'large') as $size) {
          if(preg_match('/size_{$size}/', $custom_sizes['size'])) {
               $price = $custom_sizes['price'];
          }
    }
```

The problem in here is that in my `if` condition, I want to obtain results like:

size_small, size_medium and size_large but failed to do so since it treats it as a whole string. How to properly do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use double-quotes.

But also, you can do alternation:

```
if( preg_match("/size_(?P<size>small|medium|large)/", $input, $match)) {
    $size = $match['size'];
}
```